# Convergence of a series of integrals: $S=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{t e^t}\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Let

$$S = -\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{te^t}\,dt + \int_{2}^{3}\frac{1}{te^t}\,dt-\int_{3}^{4}\frac{1}{te^t}\,dt + \cdots +\text{ad inf}$$

Does the series $S$ converge? Clearly,

$$S=\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{t e^t}\,dt$$

So I thought of using alternating series test as there is a $(-1)^{n}$ term, but I am not sure how to estimate the integral term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $1/te^t$ is a monotone decreasing function as $t$ grows. Thus (readily evident from the interpretation of an integral as signed area),

$$\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{te^t} dt \le \frac{1}{ne^n}$$

I believe this should be enough to get you to the desired conclusion.

Comment: This doesn't show that the sequence of the unsigned terms is decreasing though, as it required by the alternating series test.

Comment: Correct, but I'm not going to spell out every detail for the OP either. (Reason being this seems like a homework question so I imagine it's in everyone's best interests only to give nudges in the right direction, rather than solutions that can be readily just copied into an assignment blindly.) This bit of information is the main hurdle; I imagine they can fill in the rest of the details themselves. "Teach a man to fish," as it were.

Answer (score 1):

The function
\begin{equation}
f(t)=\frac{1}{te^t}
\end{equation}
is continuous, strictly decreasing on $[1,+\infty)$ and its limit as $t\to+\infty$ is $0$. This is enough to conclude that the terms
\begin{equation}
a_n=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{te^t}\,\text{d}t
\end{equation}
are decreasing and converge to $0$ as $n\to+\infty$. Indeed, by the mean value theorem, there are $t_n\in[n,n+1]$ and $t_{n+1}\in[n+1,n+2]$ such that $a_n=f(t_n)$ and $a_{n+1}=f(t_{n+1})$, thus $a_n=f(t_n)>f(t_{n+1})=a_{n+1}$ and $a_n=f(t_n)\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$. All the requirements of the alternating series test are therefore fulfilled and allow to conclude that the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Set $$b_n=\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{t e^t}\,dt,$$
then $$\frac{1}{(n+1)e^{n+1}}\leq b_n\leq\frac{1}{ne^{n}},$$
and using squeeze theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}{b_n}=0.$$

Obviously, $\{b_n\}$ is decreasing, therefore $S=\sum_n{(-1)^nb_n}$ is convergent.